# Do nothing if the same function is already running

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that runs every 3 seconds, is there any way to do nothing if a previous instance of the function is already running?

Comment: JavaScript code is never run concurrently, unless you use web workers... do you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are running heavy function with `setInterval` and want to skip one tick if previous one has not completed.

Then, instead of

```
function yourfoo() {
   // code
}

setInterval(yourfoo, 3000);
```

do:

```
function yourfoo() {
   // code
   setTimeout(yourfoo, 3000);
}

setTimeout(yourfoo, 3000);
```

This guarantees next call is not scheduled until previous one is completed.

Comment: Remember that fired calls of one setInterval type will get dropped if there is already one in the calling queue. So rewriting is only necessary if you do not want the code to get executed back-to-back if your code take longer to finish than the stated timeout. Otherwise it does not matter. In any case: your code will not get executed twice at the same time due to the single threaded nature of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This is done by default.

It's called JavaScript is single threaded.

Two functions can't run at the same time.

Your probably using `setInterval` which will internally buffer function calls until any currently running code is finished.

Answer (score 0):

you could define a boolean flag to indicate the running state of the function on a higher scope, and switch it on or off accordingly.

Comment: There is no need for that. Two functions can't run at the same time. You don't need a locking mechanism like this.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded, meaning that only one block of JavaScript will get executed at a given time. So even when the timer fires the execution of the code will be queued until the next available moment. Important to know is that if you're using a setInterval only one interval "fire" will get queued and all others will be dropped until there are no more intervals of this type on the queue.

Here's a great explanation of how this works by jQuery's father John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

You could rewrite your code to use setTimeout, because that way you're guaranteed that the next executing of the code will only take place after waiting at least the stated number of milliseconds (can be more if execution is blocked). Using setInterval the blocking could result in a back-to-back execution of the code if the code takes a long time to finish.

So, do something like this to prevent the back-to-back execution:

```
var nrOfMillisecondsToWait = 200;
setTimeout(function() {
  .. your code here
}, nrOfMillisecondsToWait);
```